# Android screen orientation handling issue

Tags: java, android, andengine, screen-orientation, live-wallpaper

I'm working on the android live wallpaper applications and need to correctly handle screen orientation changes.

Currently I use `onConfigurationChanged` for this purpose(in this method I need to change coordinates of my LWP screen elements. I use `andengine`). Everything works fine on the emulators and my test phones, but some my customers with **Samsung Galaxy Note2 (t03g)**, **LG thrill(LGE LG-P925)** reports the issues with incorrect application work during the screen orientations change.

I don't have these phones on hand, but can suppose that the issue is related to `onConfigurationChanged` not being called.

Is it correct to use `onConfigurationChanged` method ? Maybe I need to use `onSurfaceChanges` or something like that ? Could you please suggest me the correct way to solve this issue ?

Alos, I have added `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` into my `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<activity
            android:name=".WallpaperSettings"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my live wallpaper, which handles orientation changes, I use the `onConfigurationChange()` method to check for orientation changes, but I don't have any direct experience with the 2 phones, though I've never gotten any complaints about them. My method looks something along the lines of:

```
   @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

       // Checks the orientation of the screen  
       if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
         rotated = true;
       }
       else {
         rotated = false;
       }
   }
```

And in the `draw()` method, I check the `rotated` boolean. There's additional checks in the `onSurfaceChanged()` to correct for resolution changes when the orientation changes.

I don't have `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` in my manifest file at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

> Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size"
> also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape
> orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to
> orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as
> declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you
> must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation"
> value. That is, you must decalare
> android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". However, if your
> application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always
> handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change
> does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or
> higher device).

From http://web.archive.org/web/20120130201824/https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html